Advice and supplementary sources (videos, books) to tackle rudin's real and complex analysis exercises?
I just started grad school and I have a mandatory class in Calculus and Probability.
Professor's plan is to use baby rudin (Principles of Mathematical Analysis) and papa rudin (Real and Complex Analysis) alternating them as needed i.e. week 1: baby rudin chapters 1 and 2; week 2: papa rudin chapter 1; week 3: papa rudin chapter 2; etc
Most of my classmates and I have an economics background and have never had any proof-based class before, I am understanding the basic concepts of the theory and I can follow the theorems' proofs, but I'm having a rough time solving the exercises without looking at solutions.
I asked my professor advice on this and he said it's normal for people from economics to find this very hard, he suggested to integrate my studying with Apostol's "Mathematical Analysis" for an easier approach on the theory, but I'm still finding Rudin's exercises virtually unapproachable.
In conclusion, my question is, how to tackle proofs and exercises? Are there any sources for easier exercises which can help me "build up" to Rudin's level? Of course I'm open to learn from the very basics of what's needed.
Thank you in advance.

Do these mandatory classes absolutely require of you to have theoretical based mathematical training?

Not formally, as I and many others have been admitted to the course with no such training. But in practice, definitely would have preferred having a heads-up.

A post virtually identical to this was made earlier in the month (and apparently deleted).  The consensus was you are unlikely to do well in the class with zero background in proofs.  Rather than asking for advice from people who study math, I'd suggest asking for advice from people who study econ and survived your class in a prior year.

Rudin’s books on analysis are known to be amongst the hardest in this particular topic - but perhaps that represents an exciting challenge, and one which if you can tackle, will represent a significant achievement. I’ll break a guide to how to understanding Rudin into a few steps.
1.) Get good at proofs:
If you haven’t done a lot of mathematical proofs before, this can be a challenge on its own - but a very exciting one, which represents a step towards the ‘mathematical mindset’.
There isn’t a magic wand to get good at this, but this is plenty of resources to help you!
To start with I recommend the book ‘Proofs Without Words’ by Nelson. This book develops a range of mathematical proofs visually. The reason that I recommend this is because if you can think visually about a proof, there’s a good step, as it can help you to start making sense of the topics and components involved.  Ever underestimate how much a picture or a few scribbled thoughts can help. See here for the book: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Proofs-without-Words-Exercises-Classroom/dp/0883857006
My second recommendation is to have a look at introductions to university maths and proofs. One particular recommendation is the course that Oxford have uploaded in its entirety to YouTube called 'Introduction to University Maths'. The videos are here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aS6R3epK3ms. There are problem sheets to look through so you can practice too. See here: https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/course/view.php?id=4938
A final recommendation for proof practice, and a very important step after you have completed the previous three, have a look at the Natural Number Game by Imperial College. It's a great resource to practice logic. See here: https://adam.math.hhu.de/
2.) Start reading through Rudin with a supplement:
The only way to start is to, well, start! Begin reading through Rudin. Don't panic if you don't understand something - no-one said you were only allowed to use Rudin. My go-to analysis book for when I need a little intuition is Tao's book on analysis. Tao is an incredible mathematician, perhaps one of the best of this time, but he is also a great teacher. His book is intuitive and makes no steps without explaination, everything he says in it is built-up to. See here for this resource: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/analysis-i/.
While you read through it, don't be afraid to make a note on a post-it of what areas you haven't quite understood. You can consult Stack Exchange, lecture notes, or other textbooks to gain some understanding of these areas. Rudin is a great book, but is perhaps more of a reference book, so why not use it as a guide for topics and then consult other resources as needed.
3.) Handle the exercises:
Some exercises in the textbook may be easy, but some will be incredibly tricky. Don't panic. First of all, see what questions you can answer and do these. Then consult the questions you can't. Get a piece of paper and scribble down topics, definitions, theorems - anything which may help with this. Attempt the problem. If, say, you work at it for hours with no avail, put down the question. Sleep on it. Perhaps don't think of it for a few days. And only then, come back to it. With a fresh head you may have a new perspective.
If you're still stuck on a problem - why not ask a course friend. Discuss it together, maybe using a whiteboard to doodle out your ideas together. Maths can be collaborative. If this isn't possible, consult Stack Exchange. If you are stuck on the problem, the likelihood is so are others - and they may have asked it here!
And if not, consult the various solution manuals online. This is of course a good idea if you are not sure on your answer too. An example is here: https://linearalgebras.com/solution-baby-rudin.html
I hope this helps. Lot's of people have found Rudin's book to be tricky, but I'm sure it will feel like an amazing feeling after completing the course.
